# Include columns from one data frame from another with pandas using conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames:

**df1 - includes organization data related to accounting**

[image]

**df2 - is a master list of marketing data for organizations**

[image]

Org ID is what links the data. My goal is to generate a 3rd data frame that will add Interest and Segment columns to the first data frame based on on Org ID.

I know that merge/concat will combine these dfs for me but I want my 3rd df to only include the rows from df1 with the 2 additional columns.

Basically, what I am trying to do is use df2 as a master list from which I can grab additional data for orgs based on Org ID.

Is there a way to do this? If/else and a for loop of some kind?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on='Org ID',how='left')`

Comment: Wow...how did I miss that. I was doing df3 = merge(df1, df2....)Thanks!

Comment: also , if you want to only keep OrgId and two additional `df2.set_index('Org ID').reindex(df1['Org ID']).reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yw~ just too lazy to add an answer ~ :-)